# Faces overlapping vertexes but it's not overlapping faces?

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm new to blender and my model had this weird thing going on where the vertexes and edges don't line up with the faces at all.
The vertexes are underneath the faces and the edges clip through them.
At first I thought maybe the faces would be double since it looked like it, so I tried removing one of them. It wasn't double AND the face I removed, left a round hole, despite the edges around it forming a square.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I was following a tutorial, but their head form was a lot simpler than mine. I turned down the *Levels Viewport* in the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* from 1 to 0. It appears to be fixed now.

[image]